# How to return the result of a Solidity view method from a javascript function?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to determine a view function of a smart contract result in web3js 1.x

Suppose we have a view function `getName(uint code)` and want to get the name of a person having his code. So we write:

```
contract.methods.getName(code).call(option)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

We want to define a function to return the result name and do something with it.

How can we relate the defined function and method call?

For example:

```
async function name(code) {
  contract.methods.getName(code).call(option)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
  return ???
}

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  let x = name(i);
  // Do something with x, for example:
  alert(x); 
}
```

P.S: I know that the result is accessible inside `.then` body, but I want to access it inside the `name` function scope and return it from the function.

Answer (score 2):

You already using async so you can just use await

```
var result = await contract.methods.getName(code).call(option)
```